# Unable to run pyshark.FileCapture(pcap) inside a QThread class in linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, qthread, pyside2, pyshark

I have a PySide2 Application that works in windows. What it does is that it opens a network packet (pcap) file using the python pyshark library inside a QThread class. It is able to open that pcap file but when i tried to run the same app on ubuntu, it throws an error. RuntimeError: Cannot add child handler, the child watcher does not have a loop attached.

I have searched online for solutions and stumbled across this site ->  https://github.com/KimiNewt/pyshark/issues/303

It seems that pyshark can only run in the main thread and not in the sub-thread.
I have also created a minimal example that replicates my problem as shown below.

```
import sys
import pyshark
import asyncio
from PySide2.QtCore import QThread, Qt, Slot
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton


class SubThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SubThread, self).__init__()
        self.Input_file = "profibus.pcap"

    def run(self):
        print("thread is running!")
        cap = pyshark.FileCapture(self.Input_file)
        iter_obj = iter(cap)
        pkt = next(iter_obj)
        print(pkt)
        cap.close()

class TopLayout(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, sub_thread):
        self.frame = QFrame()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.sub_thread = sub_thread

        self.toggle_button_box = QHBoxLayout()
        self.toggle_button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.toggle_button.setCheckable(True)
        self.toggle_button_box.addWidget(self.toggle_button)

        self.layout.addLayout(self.toggle_button_box)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.frame.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.toggle_button.clicked.connect(self.on_toggle_button_clicked)



    @Slot()
    def on_toggle_button_clicked(self):
        self.sub_thread.start()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.SubThread = SubThread()
        self.top_layout = TopLayout(self.SubThread)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.top_layout.frame)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    # Execute application
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My current environment configs are:

- Python 3.7,
- Pyside2 5.13.2,
- Pyshark 0.4.2.9 (latest)